# Optimizing SQL WHERE for calculating distance between latitude and longitude positions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm creating a database that is being hosted on a MS SQL 2012 server. The primary function of this database is to return results that is within a certain distance from an origin. Locations are being stored as latitude / longitude.

By reading here on Stack Overflow i found a very nice way to query the database for exactly what i am looking for and it works like a charm! However I'm thinking of a possible way to optimize this.

**Original SQL query**

```
DECLARE @orig_lat DECIMAL(12, 9)
DECLARE @orig_lng DECIMAL(12, 9)

SET @orig_lat=56.xxxxxx 
SET @orig_lng=14.xxxxxx

DECLARE @orig geography = geography::Point(@orig_lat, @orig_lng, 4326);

SELECT *
FROM foobar
WHERE @orig.STDistance(geography::Point(foobar.latitude, foobar.longitude, 4326)) < 2000
```

My guess is that this query does a linear search of the ***foobar*** table only returning the matching columns. However since this table contains positions all over the world I want to know if I can help the database by reducing the amount of rows it has to run the distance calculation on. My guess is that this calculation is heavy for the server.

I know the origin of the request being made and I also know that the maximum distance between the points will never be larger than lets say 100km.

**Hypothesis**

Since I know that I don't have to search the whole world only up to 100km from point of origin I can improve upon the WHERE statement as seen below. By creating a minimum and maximum bound for the latitude and longitude that is done by moving the position by some number in each direction.

I explain:

- Origin latitude 56.xxxxxx
- Min latitude 55.xxxxxx
- Max latitude 57.xxxxxx
- Origin longitude 14.xxxxxx
- Min longitude 13.xxxxxx
- Max longitude 15.xxxxxx

By doing this I create a zone around the origin reaching about 126km. By adding this to the WHERE statement I first make sure the requested position is within the correct bounds. After that I run the distance calculation to get exact distance. The distance calculation is now only run against the rows that is within the min and max bounds instead of the whole world.

**Optimization proposal**

```
DECLARE @orig_lat DECIMAL(12, 9)
DECLARE @orig_lng DECIMAL(12, 9)
DECLARE @orig_latMin DECIMAL(12, 9)
DECLARE @orig_latMax DECIMAL(12, 9)
DECLARE @orig_lngMin DECIMAL(12, 9)
DECLARE @orig_lngMax DECIMAL(12, 9)

SET @orig_lat=56.xxxxxx
SET @orig_lng=14.xxxxxx
SET @orig_latMin=55.xxxxxx 
SET @orig_latMax=57.xxxxxx
SET @orig_lngMin=13.xxxxxx
SET @orig_lngMax=15.xxxxxx

DECLARE @orig geography = geography::Point(@orig_lat, @orig_lng, 4326);

SELECT *
FROM foobar
WHERE ([latitude] > @orig_latMin
    AND [latitude] < @orig_latMax 
    AND [longitude] > @orig_lngMin 
    AND [longitude] < @orig_lngMax)
    AND @orig.STDistance(geography::Point(foobar.latitude, foobar.longitude,   4326)) < 2000
```

I don't know database implementation details but does this improve the query or does it make it worse? My guess is that it depends on how the WHERE statement actually work and in what order it dose things. My hope is that the boundary checks will be run before the distance calculation in order to reduce the amount of time a distance calculation is done.

**EDIT**

Just implemented the suggested index proposal with the following results.

Without indexing:

- With optimized statement have a cost of **0,025352**
- Without optimized statement have a cost of **0,025323**

With indexing:

- With optimized statement have a cost of **0,0104057**
- Without optimized statement have a cost of **0,0253234**

Comment: Check the execution plan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good rule of thumb is that the execution time of a database query depends on the number of disk pages that have to be read. The CPU time can usually be ignored.

According to this rule, your proposed optimization will improve the execution time if it makes a difference for the number of disk pages. This will be the case if there is an index on *latitude* and *longitude* that will allow to skip many table rows and therefore many disk pages. If that's the case, the optimizer will certainly evalute that part of the WHERE clause before the distance.

If there's no index that helps with those two columns, I doubt you will see a big difference.

Comment: If i understand you correct. By editing the foobar table and adding an index like this. `CREATE INDEX index_position
on foobar (latitude, longitude);`
It should improve the query?

Comment: If you don't have an index on these columns yet, then add one and try it. Check the execution plan to make sure they are really used.

Comment: BTW: I'm not a specialist regarding SQLServer's spatial data support. But you should be able to save the location in a *geography* column, then create a spatial index on that column and run optimized queries on it (without the need to calculate the bounding rectangle for the distance).

Comment: Your solution works amazing! I will have a look at the geography columns later as well. Thx :)

See test results in main post.

Answer (score 0):

You can analyze the query time using MS Management Studio, run a big query with differents where's, it will even show you what part of the query requires which amount of time.

You can click CTRL+L: Display estimated executionplan
or CTRL+M: display actual execution plan (when you run it)

Run it once with the "boundaries" first, then again with boundaries after.
you will be able to see which is slower, then try again without the boundaries.

If you don't have enough data the difference might not be visible.